# How to parse a byte stream into `HttpRequest` objects with akka-http?

Tags: scala, akka, pcap, akka-http

From the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.1/scala/http/common/http-model.html#parsing-rendering): "there's currently no public API provided to parse (or render to) Strings or byte arrays". How can I use a private API to parse a network stream into `HttpRequest` objects?

Also, what should the input-byte-stream be?

1. Unordered packets (ethernet and up)
2. Unordered tcp packets
3. Ordered tcp payloads (http raw requests, in order) (This is my guess)

Note:

1. My byte stream will only contain http requests, not responses
2. I'm getting this byte stream from a pcap file, not from a live http client. (Which is also why I'm asking how much I need to parse it before sending it to akka-http)
3. If you think it's a bad idea, please explain, that would be a big help too.
4. I suspect this involves using http().serverLayer. I'm not sure.

[link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/bf2m6ALd7rA): A related question in the Akka Google Group

Thanks!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @TNW, I heavily edited my question to be more specific. What do you think?

Comment: Here are [some](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/f008a932c381013f6060ee00a731862bafed2be7/akka-http-core/src/test/scala/akka/http/impl/engine/client/TlsEndpointVerificationSpec.scala) [examples](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/f008a932c381013f6060ee00a731862bafed2be7/akka-http-core/src/test/scala/akka/http/impl/engine/client/TlsEndpointVerificationSpec.scala) from akka-http unit tests, they might help

Comment: Oh, I think I see -- you want to parse a byte stream into `HttpRequest` objects in Akka?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but fiddly. I have done this, but I can't post the full code here, as it's private.

The relevant AKKA code which does this is in [`HttpRequestParser`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/impl/engine/parsing/HttpRequestParser.scala)

Most of the code is package-private, so you'll need to write a helper class of your own in the `akka.http` package to get access to it.

The code will look something like this:

```
package akka.http

/**
 * This class gives us access to Akka's [[akka.http.impl.engine.parsing.HttpRequestParser]].
 *
 * It is in the akka package, as most of Akka's parsing code is package-private.
 *
 * @see [[akka.http.impl.engine.server.HttpServerBluePrint]]
 */    
class HttpRequestParserHelper()(
    implicit system: ActorSystem,
    materializer: Materializer) {

  def unmarshalRequest(wireFormat: Array[Byte]): HttpRequest = {

    val input = ByteString(wireFormat)

    val requestFuture = Source.single(input)
      .via(requestParsingFlow())
      .runWith(Streams.getSingleElement)
      .transform(identity, e =>
        new IOException("Error unmarshalling request", e))

    Await.result(requestFuture, 10.seconds)
  }

  /**
   * An Akka Flow which parses incoming ByteStrings and emits HttpRequests.
   *
   * This code was copied from [[akka.http.impl.engine.server.HttpServerBluePrint]]
   */
  private def requestParsingFlow(): Flow[ByteString, HttpRequest, Any] = {
    ... 
  }
}
```

Fill in `requestParsingFlow` from the AKKA source code, removing the bits which aren't applicable until it compiles.

The input data needs to be the TCP stream data, i.e. option (3) from your question.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One method is to do the following

Include `libraryDependencies += "com.athaydes.rawhttp" % "rawhttp-core" % "2.4.1"` in your project.

Then parse the `byteString` to `RawHttpRequest`. This however is not regular akka `HttpRequest` but one can create `HttpRequest` from `RawHttpRequest`

```
    case Received(data) =>
      val decoded = data.utf8String
      val rawHttp = new RawHttp
      val rawHttpRequest = rawHttp.parseRequest(data.utf8String)
```